# Colour gradient in bubble plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I m defining color based on threshold. But is there a way to give a color gradient ?

```
df %>%
  mutate(X_value = 'Term') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=X_value,y=p_value)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=abs(p_value)), 
             color = dplyr::case_when(df$p_value > -6 ~ "red", 
                                      df$p_value < 6 ~ "blue")) +
  
  geom_label_repel(aes(label=Pathway), size=3) +
  labs(y=NULL, x = NULL,color='p_value',size='p_value'
```

This gives me this one [image: one]

This code

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=p_value,y=Term)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=p_value,size=p_value)) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(5)) +
  labs(
    x='p_value', y=NULL,
    color='p_value',size='p_value'
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_text(face='bold'),
    axis.text = element_text(face='bold')
  )
```

Gives me this

[image: Second one]

I would like to have the first one as well as I would like to put a color gradient which is seen in the second pic. Not sure how to do it since the first fig the threshold is based on a cutoff which labels it.

my data

```
structure(list(Term = c("Reactome Gene Sets", "GO Biological Processes", 
"GO Biological Processes", "GO Biological Processes", "GO Biological Processes", 
"GO Biological Processes"), Pathway = c("R-MMU-191273", "GO:0034341", 
"GO:0050900", "GO:0046942", "GO:0001817", "GO:0048871"), VVV = c("Cholesterol biosynthesis", 
"response to interferon-gamma", "leukocyte migration", "carboxylic acid transport", 
"regulation of cytokine production", "multicellular organismal homeostasis"
), p_value = c(-11.6414922875, -9.3148301923, -6.2150336681, 
-5.9190690396, -5.8467499202, -5.767770517)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a gradient on one of the categories and use gray as the other category, e.g.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(X_value = "Term") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = X_value, y = p_value)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = abs(p_value), color = p_value)) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = Pathway), size=3) +
  labs(y = NULL, x = NULL) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(5), limits = c(-12, -6), breaks = c(-6, -12))
```

[image: example_3.png]

Comment: same doubt as i posted for other answer "so i loose the threshold labeling which i tried to do and which gives me "red"  "blue" color?"

Comment: The threshold is still "-6"; the values above -6 are grey, the values below -6 are coloured with the gradient

Answer (score 1):

You could use this kind of code:

```
df %>%
  mutate(X_value = 'Term') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=X_value,y=p_value)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=abs(p_value), 
                 color = df$p_value)) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(5))+
  
  geom_label_repel(aes(label=Pathway), size=3) +
  labs(y=NULL, x = NULL,color='p_value',size='p_value')
```

[image]

Comment: so i loose the threshold labeling which i tried to do and which gives me "red"  "blue" color?

Comment: My doubt got clarified from @jared_mamrot answer ..thanks a lot for the quick answer